# Remove blue line from Eclipse tabs

Tags: eclipse

I've just installed Eclipse 2024-03 and it shows a blue line for the active tab:

[image: blue line on the active package explorer]

I understand that this is for accessibility (some people can't see the difference between the white active tab and the grey inactive tabs).

But for me the blue line is somehow distracting, as my real "focus" is where the cursor is blinking.

Does anyone know how to turn that line off or change at least its color? I can't find an option under Preferences / General / Appearance.

Comment: Looks like this is set by the `swt-selected-tab-highlight` property in the CSS, it doesn't look like it can be configured other than editing the CSS.

Comment: Ah, it is defined in the theme. In that case I just create my own theme. Thanks a lot.